# Cannot understand how to implement Memoization of a function with Guava

Tags: java, guava, memoization

I have a Java class that contains the following function I want to memoize to improve performance:

```java
 private Boolean processFilterByPackage(JetbrainsSnippet item, PsiFile file) {
        PackageProviderProcessor processor = packageProviderProcessorFactory
                .createFromProvider(item.getContext()
                        .getPackageProvider()
                        .getProvider()
                );

        return processor.process(item, file);
    }
```

I am trying to use Guava, following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-memoizer) tutorial, but I can´t get my head to understand how it works.

I have this, right now.

```
LoadingCache<Boolean, ??> memo = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build(CacheLoader.from(this::processFilterByPackage));
```

How do I specify the arguments of my function and how to properly define the "callback" function in the "CacheLoader.from" method as it complains it cannot resolve the method.
I guess the method must return a Function instead but not sure how.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that LoadingCache only supports methods with a single parameter.

I solve this, by wrapping the two arguments I needed in a Pair:

```
private final LoadingCache<Pair<PackageContext, PsiFile>, Boolean> memoizedFilterByPackageFn =
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
      .expireAfterAccess(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .build(CacheLoader.from(this::processFilterByPackage));
```